# C# SQL Query in public DataTable

Tags: c#, sql

I have this public DataTable that I am trying to run an sql query in, but the dang thing wont work...

```
public DataTable get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(Int64 orderID)
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection(objCommon.IpcConnectionString);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.OrderTransaction_Master where orderID = " + orderID, cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

I get a red line under `get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID` saying

```
Error   3   'OrderTransaction_Master.get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long)': not all code paths return a value    C:\IPC\App_Code\OrderTransaction_Master.cs  32  22  http://localhost/ipc/
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of your method is a `DataTable`, but you don't have a return statement in your method. You are also executing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, where you should be doing `cmd.ExecuteReader()` and loading a `DataTable`

```
public DataTable get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(Int64 orderID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(var cn = new SqlConnection(objCommon.IpcConnectionString))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "select * from dbo.OrderTransaction_Master where orderID = " + orderID, cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cn.Open();
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(reader);            
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` in `using` statements. This will properly dispose of the objects (close the connections, etc) once the using statement is exited.

Comment: I got an error for the SqlReader `Error 3 The type or namespace name 'SqlReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\IPC\App_Code\OrderTransaction_Master.cs 40 9 http://localhost/ipc/
`

Comment: I still get the same erro `Error 3 'OrderTransaction_Master.get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long)': not all code paths return a value C:\IPC\App_Code\OrderTransaction_Master.cs 33 22 http://localhost/ipc/
` from before

Answer (score 0):

your return type is a DataTable but your function doesn't return anything.

2 things, change the function to void, or return a dataTable

Answer (score -1):

This method will help you no end. It is my baby, and is a real beaut.

It accepts your SQLQuery as a parameter and returns a DataTable object:

```
public DataTable DBGetDataTable(string SQLQuery)
{
    string MethodName = "public DataTable DBGetDataTable(string SQLQuery)";
    DataTable Result = null;
    SqlConnection SqlConnection = null;
    SqlCommand SqlCommand = null;
    try
    {
        string DatabaseName = "";
        string ServerNameOrIP = "";
        string DatabaseUserID = "";
        string Password = "";

        string ConnectionString = "database=" + DatabaseName + ";server=" + ServerNameOrIP + ";user ID=" + DatabaseUserID + ";PWD=" + Password + ";Connection Timeout=5000";

        SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, SqlConnection);

        SqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader SqlDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (SqlDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

            Dt.Load(SqlDataReader);

            Result = Dt;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Common.Exception(ClassName, MethodName, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlConnection.Close();
        SqlConnection.Dispose();
        SqlConnection = null;

        SqlCommand.Dispose();
        SqlCommand = null;

    }
    return Result;
}
```

Since your database credentials will be different to mine, you will need to supply values for the following variables within the above code:

- string DatabaseName = "";
- string ServerNameOrIP = "";
- string DatabaseUserID = "";
- string Password = "";

It is very resilient and it cleans up after itself very efficiently, and as such is designed for heavy database use.

Here is an example of it being used:

```
    StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" SET DATEFORMAT DMY");

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" SELECT");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("      TillPayment.TillPaymentId As Id");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.TransactionGuid As TransactionCode");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.Amount As Price");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.DiscountPercentage");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.Processed As ProcessedDate");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , PaymentType.Name As PaymentType");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.ItemType As Item");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillUser.LoginCode As Login");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillUser.Name As UserName");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , TillPayment.TillName As Till");

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" FROM");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    [tblTillPayment] TillPayment");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    INNER JOIN [tblPaymentType] PaymentType ON TillPayment.PaymentTypeId = PaymentType.PaymentTypeId");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    INNER JOIN [tblTillUser] TillUser ON TillPayment.TillLoginCode = TillUser.LoginCode");

    int SelectedMonthFrom = GetMonthAsNumber(CboMonthReportMonth.SelectedItem.Text);

    int SelectedYearFrom = int.Parse(CboMonthReportYear.SelectedItem.Text);

    int SelectedMonthTo = SelectedMonthFrom == 12 ? 1 : SelectedMonthFrom + 1;

    int SelectedYearTo = SelectedMonthTo == 1 ? SelectedYearFrom + 1: SelectedYearFrom;

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" WHERE");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    Processed >= '01-" + SelectedMonthFrom + "-" + SelectedYearFrom + " 00:00'");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    AND Processed < '01-" + SelectedMonthTo + "-" + SelectedYearTo + " 00:00'");

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" AND NOT(TillUser.LoginCode = '2503' or TillUser.LoginCode = '1453')");

    sbSQL.AppendLine(" ORDER BY");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    Till");
    sbSQL.AppendLine("    , Processed");

    DataTable DtReport = DBGetDataTable(sbSQL.ToString());
```

Of course, your SQL query will differ from mine.

Notice, I have used a StringBuilder object, but if you're more comfortable writing directly to a string then you may do that instead.

You wrote

> I still get the same erro Error 3
>   'OrderTransaction_Master.get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long)':
>   not all code paths return a value
>   C:\IPC\App_Code\OrderTransaction_Master.cs 33 22 http:// localhost/ipc/
>   from before

This suggests that thereis no default return value for the method called OrderTransaction get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long OrderId)

I'd imagine the method in question should look something like the following:

```
    public OrderTransaction get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long OrderId)
    {
        string MethodName = "public OrderTransaction get_OrderTransaction_Master_ByOrderID(long OrderId)";
        OrderTransaction Result = null;
        try{
            StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();

            sbSQL.AppendLine(" SELECT");
            sbSQL.AppendLine("    *");

            sbSQL.AppendLine(" FROM");
            sbSQL.AppendLine("    dbo.OrderTransaction_Master");

            sbSQL.AppendLine(" WHERE");
            sbSQL.AppendLine("    OrderID = " + OrderID);

            DataTable Dt = DBGetDataTable(sbSQL.ToString())

            OrderTransaction OrderTransaction = new OrderTransaction(Dt);

            Result = OrderTransaction;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Common.Exception(ClassName,MethodName,ex);
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

Please ask if you have any questions.